# How to use axioms to prove a derivation in propositional calculus?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-systems

Given a formal system called "$P0$" that has 1 rule (Modus Ponens) and 3 axioms:

$1.$ $\alpha$ $\rightarrow$$(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$    --- (Ak)

$2.$ $(\alpha \rightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \gamma)) \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \beta ) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \gamma))$ --- (AS)

$3.$ $(\lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot \alpha) \rightarrow ((\lnot \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \rightarrow \beta)$  --- (A$\lnot$)

How do I replace the wff of the axioms with real wff to prove a derivation like : $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$.

What wff should I use to set up the derivation and use the axioms to prove it?

Comment: You can find many proofs of it on this site. Try with tags: propositional-calculus and hilbert-system

Answer (score 1):

That one is well known, but hard to come up with by yourself from scratch, certainly when you just begin to study this system. Indeed, typically textbooks will just provide this one:

$1. \ (\alpha \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) \rightarrow \alpha) \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha))  \quad (AS)$

$2. \ \alpha \rightarrow ((\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \rightarrow \alpha) \quad (Ak)$

$3. \ (\alpha \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \quad (MP \ 1,2)$

$4. \ \alpha \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \quad (Ak)$

$5. \ \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \quad (MP \ 3,4)$

Comment: Yes, my question is : how do I use the Axioms, what wff do I have , what stuff that I can replace with $\beta$? I don't need the proof, but the steps that I should follow to write those lines

Comment: @Bleeeaa So if you look at my line 1:  I used $\alpha$ for $\alpha$, $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ for $\beta$, and $\alpha$ for $\gamma$.  So the general idea is: you can use any expression for any variable, as long as you do it consistently.

Comment: So the only wff I can use are $\alpha$ and $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$? How do I decide what wff can I use to prove something ?

Comment: @Bleeeaa No, it really can be *anything*. For example, $(\neg P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (\neg \neg R \rightarrow (\neg P \rightarrow Q))$ would be a perfectly good instance of axiom $(Ak)$. So it's not a matter of deciding which one you *can* use (you can use *any*), but which ones would actually be useful to use in getting towards your goal.

Comment: So if I want to prove $\lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \vdash \lnot \beta$ can I use $(\lnot \lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot \beta) \rightarrow \lnot \beta$? Known that $\lnot \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \vdash \alpha$. And why can't I use $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ to prove $\lnot  \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \vdash \alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in response to another of the OP's questions along the same lines: The axiom system you are being asked to use is a standard one -- famously used in the classic textbook Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (many editions, there is bound to be one in the library).

Since you are evidently *very* unclear what the rules of the deduction game are, you badly need to pause and take a slow and careful look at e.g. Mendelson's text.