# Replacing set of tautologies with a single formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Here is a question I have about first order logic using the conventions in Enderton:

First-order deductions in our proof system are obtained via 1) being a member of a set of formulas $\Gamma$, 2) being an instance of six axioms, the set of which we call $\Lambda$, [image]
or 3) obtained via modus ponens from formulas obtained in the previous two ways. Now, consider that the first axiom is that we have an infinite set of first-order tautologies.

(1) Could we have replaced this infinite set of tautologies by a single formula?
(2) Could we have replaced this infinite set of tautologies set by a single formula schema? (where we define a schema as being obtained by quantifying over
all possible subformulas) i.e., some formula containing generic subformulas.

Here are my thoughts: For question (1), I believe that it is not the case that we can replace all tautologies with a single formula. The obvious candidate is the formula consisting of the conjunction of all tautologies, let's call this formula $\psi$. This formula would be of countable length, but determining whether we are able to write a given formula $\varphi$ in any deduction would no longer involve simply checking whether $\varphi \in \Lambda$. We would now need to check whether $\vdash \{\psi, \varphi\}$ or equivalently $\{\psi, \varphi\}$ is consistent, which presents an equally complicated problem and requires the use of the infinite set of tautologies to determine.

For question (2), the obvious candidate is the schema $\alpha \leftrightarrow (\beta \rightarrow \beta)$ for an atomic formula $\beta$, (which we can easily convert to the limited language provided be Enderton). We are simply providing a formula which checks whether some formula $\alpha$ is tautologically implied by a known tautology. Now, I am not certain whether verification of whether this holds requires the infinite set of tautologies.

I'd greatly appreciate any tips as to whether I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) Could we have replaced this infinite set of tautologies by a single formula? (2) Could we have replaced this infinite set of tautologies set by a single formula schema?

Yes; there are many equivalent axiomatization of *propositional calculus* that needs only *modus ponens* as rule of inference.

A very "classic" one is the three-axioms set used by Mendelson (see e.g. this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633245/how-to-use-axioms-to-prove-a-derivation-in-propositional-calculus)).

You can see [List of Hilbert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) for many other axiom systems, including the single-axiom systems proposed by Łukasiewicz-Tarski and Meredith (for systems with $\to$ and $\lnot$ as primitive).

---

*Comments*: the conjunction of all tautologies is not a well-formed formula of "standard" propositional and first-order logics, where a formula must have finite lenght.

The schema $α ↔ (β → β)$ is not a tautology, and thus it is not allowed as axiom, because it implies the inconsistency of the system.

Comment: suppose I try to show the tautologies can be replaced by a single axiom system like one of the Łukasiewicz-Tarski ones. Is there a single axiom like these that relies solely on traditional modus ponens as the rule of inference and is truth functionally complete?

Comment: Also, to prove that a system with a single axiom such as $((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (C\rightarrow D))\rightarrow ((D\rightarrow A)\rightarrow(E\rightarrow(C\rightarrow A)))$ is complete, is it still trivial that if $\vDash_\mathcal{A} ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (C\rightarrow D))\rightarrow ((D\rightarrow A)\rightarrow(E\rightarrow(C\rightarrow A)))$, then $\vdash ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (C\rightarrow D))\rightarrow ((D\rightarrow A)\rightarrow(E\rightarrow(C\rightarrow A)))$?

Comment: Also, how do I extend this idea of a single-axiom proof system to schema? Isn't this a trivial extension, merely replacing the atoms $A,B,C,D,E$ with formulas?

Comment: @Raton - Yes; the single-axiom system with *modus ponens* is sound and complete for classical propositional logic. Of course, it must be formulated as a schema (replace $A,B,C,\ldots$ with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$).

Comment: How should I go about a proof of this--doesn't the lack of tautologies that we can write impact steps other than the base case of showing that the axiom itself is sound?

Comment: Also, is the schema simply the atomic formula but replaced with arbitrary formulas?

Comment: How does the proof of the schema case differ from the formula case other than the fact that the base cases of induction are different?

Comment: @Raton - we can develop the calculus with formulas as axiom: in this case we need a rule fof substitution of formulas in place of atoms, or with schema (i.e. made with meta-variables standing for formulas) in which case the subst is built-in into the schema.

Comment: I still can't think of what formula we can use to replace the first axiom (namely the set of tautologies) in 6-axiom system that I posted an image of. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: @Raton - in the post [how-to-use-axioms-to-prove-a-derivation-in-propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633245/how-to-use-axioms-to-prove-a-derivation-in-propositional-calculus) that I've already linked above, you can find the "best known" three-axioms schema system.

Comment: For the single-axiom schema, use Łukasiewicz-Tarski above.